# How to change value to a variable once it is declared in html file of Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on ionic 3 where I want to assign value to the variable in the view

My problem is :

I have set value of `shake == 0` in my `.ts` file.

When value of shake variable changes, it shakes the div file, but as I have assigned the userId to the shake variable in the html file so shake holds the userId value, and html file loads after .ts file ,so value of shake remain unchanged even if we try to change the value of shake in .ts file

For example:

I want that after assigning value `playerValue.playerUid` to the variable (`shake==playerValue.playerUid`)

variable value  should be 0 .

In Angular may be we can do it by `ngTemplateOutletContext`, but how can we do it in Ionic?

HTML markup below

```
<ion-content no-padding>
  <div class="create-team-section">
    <ion-list class="team-create-list">
      <div [ngSwitch]="playerType" *ngFor="let playerValue of players |
          search : terms| sort: {property: column, order: order}; let i = index">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="playerValue.playerType" ngSelected="selected">
          <ion-item [class.active]="playerValue.isSelected? 'active' : null">
            <ion-grid no-padding>
              <!-- <a (click)="playerInfo()"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></a> -->
              <ion-row align-items-center (click)='fin();' [class.shake]="shake==playerValue.playerUid ? 'shake' : null">
                <ion-col col-3>
                  <!-- <div class="create-team-imge" >
                      <img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}>
                    </div> -->
                  <div class="create-team-imge">
                    <ion-avatar item-star no-line>
                      <button (click)="playerinfo(i)"><img src={{playerValue.playerPhoto}}></button>
                    </ion-avatar>
                    <ion-badge>
                      <ion-icon name="information"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-badge>
                  </div>

                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-md-9 col-9 (click)="setClickedRow(i)">
                  <ion-row align-items-center>
                    <ion-col col-md-8 col-7>

                      <p>{{playerValue.playerName}}</p>
                      <p>Selected By {{playerValue.selectedBy}}</p>
                      <p class="country" >{{playerValue.teamName}}</p>
                      <p class="points"> Points:
                        <span>{{playerValue.totalPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col col-md-4 col-5 class="cradit">
                      <p>
                        <span>{{playerValue.playerCreditPoint}}</span>
                      </p>
                      <button ion-button icon-only>
                        <ion-icon [name]="playerValue.isSelected? 'close' : 'ios-checkmark'"></ion-icon>
                      </button>
                    </ion-col>
                  </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

.ts code

```
export class CreateteamPage {

shake: any = 0;


fin(){
    this.shake = 1;

    alert(this.shake);
  }

  playerSelection(playerType, index) {
    console.log('total player ' + this.totalPlayer);
    console.log('index  ' + this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].maxSelection);
    if (this.totalCreaditPoint < parseFloat(this.players[index].playerCreditPoint)) {
      // if (this.totalPlayer >= 10) {
      //   this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
      //   const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      //     message: 'u can select only 11 players',
      //     duration: 3000,
      //     position: 'top',
      //   });
      //   toast.present();
      // } else {
      if (this.totalPlayer >= 11) {
        this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'u can select only 11 players',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
        });
        toast.present();
      } else {
        this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
        const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'u dont have enough credit point',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top',
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    } else {
      if (this.players[index].playerType == playerType) {
        if (
          this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].countSelection >=
          this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].maxSelection
        ) {
          this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
          const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message:
              'Select maximun ' +
              this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].maxSelection +
              '  ' +
              this.players[index].playerType,
            duration: 3000,
            position: 'top',

          });

          toast.present();

        } else {
          if (this.totalPlayer >= 11) {
            this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
            const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'u can select only 11 players',
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top',
            });
            toast.present();
          } else {
            if (this.team1player >= 7 && this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team1Name) {
              this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
              const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'u can select only 7 player from ' + this.matchData.data.team1Name,
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'top',
              });
              toast.present();
            } else if (this.team2player >= 7 && this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team2Name) {
              this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
              const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                message: 'u can select only 7 player from ' + this.matchData.data.team2Name,
                duration: 3000,
                position: 'top',
              });
              toast.present();
            } else {
              this.players[index].isSelected = true;
              this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].countSelection =
                this.segmentButtonName[this.segmentindex].countSelection + 1;
              this.totalCreaditPoint -= parseFloat(this.players[index].playerCreditPoint);
              if (this.selectedPlayers.indexOf(this.players[index]) == -1) {
                console.log(this.players[index].teamName);
                console.log(this.matchData.data.team1Name);
                console.log(this.matchData.data.team1Name);
                if (this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team1Name) {
                  this.team1player++;
                } else if (this.players[index].teamName == this.matchData.data.team2Name) {
                  this.team2player++;
                }
                this.selectedPlayers.push(this.players[index].playerUid);
                this.storage.set('team', this.selectedPlayers);
                this.storage.get('team').then(val => {
                  console.log(val);
                });
                this.totalPlayer++;
              }
              console.log('team1player:' + this.team1player);
              console.log('team2player:' + this.team2player);
            }
          }
        }
        this.shake += this.shake;
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to assign value from HTML file?
Can't you just do it from .ts file? or else by using [(ngModel)]?

Comment: @siddharthshah please look I have modified the Question not it is more detailed

Comment: @siddharthshah on using [(ngModel)] I am facing error : CreateteamPage.html:104 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: Make sure u have imported FormsModule And    ReactiveFormsModule in your module.
i guess this will resolve attribute error

Answer (score 2):

For `104 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute error` you should specify `name` of the form control along with `[(ngModel)]`

For eg:

```
<span name="shakeFormControl" [(ngModel)]="shake"></span>
```

Another way is to try putting the `shake` variable assignment in `NgZone` like:

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    this.shake = this.players[index].playerUid;
});
```